# HttpPostedFile to stream = why shouldn't I dispose stream?

Tags: asp.net

I must save an uploaded image on a disc but first I must validate if the image hasn't got width or height smaller than 50px. As I know when we use stream then we must dispose this stream so I use 'using' in validation method:

```
public bool CheckDimensions(HttpPostedFile file)
{
    using (Stream stream = file.InputStream)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);

        if (image.PhysicalDimension.Width < 50 || image.PhysicalDimension.Height < 50)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

But then I can't save the image in my second method because the ContentLength of the HttpPostedFile file is 0. When I don't use 'using' statement the ContentLength of the HttpPostedFile is correct (> 0). So in that case I shouldn't dispose stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `file.InputStream` is reference to the uploaded file. Disposing it with `using` statement means it is disposed wherever it is also referenced/used

Try

```
using(Stream stream = file.InputStream)
{
   bool isRightSize = CheckDimensions(stream);
   ... other operations on the stream
}

public bool CheckDimensions(Stream stream)
{

        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);

        if (image.PhysicalDimension.Width < 50 || image.PhysicalDimension.Height < 50)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

}
```

Comment: Thx - should we explicitly close it because on this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx we have information "Server resources that are allocated to buffer the uploaded file will be destroyed when the request ends."

Comment: I don't think this is related. I think it means when the page post back, the file will no longer be available so you will have tp upload it again or use SaveAs to save it to disk for later use